# Driver problems with rtl8812au for Alfa AUS036ACH

Tags: networking, drivers, 17.10

I recently bought an Alfa AWUS036ACH wireless adapter and had some problems installing the drivers. After some fiddling it worked fine. But now suddenly after 2 weeks the interface doesn't show up in `ifconfig` or `iwconfig` anymore. After having tried installing many different drivers I cannot seem to get it to work anymore. I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 4.13.0-38-generic.

```
$ dmesg
usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8812
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-1: Product: 802.11n NIC
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 123456
8812au: version magic '4.13.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.13.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload '
8812au: version magic '4.13.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.13.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload '

$ dkms status
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.13.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl8812au, 5.1.5, 4.13.0-38-generic, x86_64: built
```

There are so many different drivers for rtl8812au on gitub that i'm not sure which is the newest/correct one. As a side note i need monitor mode to work.

**Edit #1**

After removing 4.3.8, installing 5.1.5 and rebooting there still is no trace of the interface. I went ahead and removed 5.1.5 aswell and tried a fresh build but cannot seem to find where i got the 5.1.5 from. So I built and installed the newest version i could find from [diederikdehaas/rtl8812au](https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU): 4.3.20 and rebooted.

Still nothing.

```
$ dmesg
8812au: version magic '4.13.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.13.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload '

$ dkms status
rtl8812AU, 4.3.20, 4.13.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)

$ sudo modprobe 8812au
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Exec format error
```

Furthermore i tried 4.3.20 on a friends laptop who is running Ubuntu 17.10 aswell and it works like a charm there...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Current working drivers with support for monitor mode are maintained directly by aircrack-ng team and available here:

https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

Answer (score 0):

We assume that the newest is the version with the highest number. It appears that you have two conflicting versions built but not actually installed. Let's remove the older one and install the newer one:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg --all
```

Now check:

```
sudo dkms status
```

That version should no longer appear. If so, please proceed:

```
sudo dkms install rtl8812au/5.1.5
```

If there are any errors or warnings, please edit your question to show them.